# Could a quantum computer factor $N=p\times q$ using Hadamard transforms on $x^2\bmod N$ (instead of Fourier transforms on $a^x\bmod N$)?

Tags: algorithms, factorization, quantum-computation

In [Classically verifiable quantum advantage from a computational Bell test](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41567-022-01643-7), Kahanamoku-Meyer, Choi, Vazirani, and Yao propose using $x^2 \bmod N$ in an interactive proof-of-quantumness.  This is a two-to-one function.

Of note, Kahanamoku-Meyer *et al.* emphasize that it is much easier to calculate the Hadamard transform of $x^2\bmod N$ than it would be to calculate the Fourier transform of $a^x\bmod N$, as in [Shor’s algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shor%27s_algorithm).  Indeed, they appear (somewhat) optimistic that $x^2\bmod N$ can be calculated in superposition for a [NISQ-era](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noisy_intermediate-scale_quantum_era) device.

In detail:

- A classical verifier picks two secret large prime numbers $(p,q)$, and provides a quantum computer the product $N=p\times q$.
- The quantum computer prepares $\sum|x\rangle|x^2\bmod N\rangle$ in superposition.
- The quantum computer measures and reports the second register in the computational basis to get an output $y$, which collapses the first register onto the two preimages that hash/map onto $y$.
- The quantum computer measures and reports the first register in the Hadamard basis to output a string $d$.
- The classical verifier uses her knowledge of $(p,q)$ as a trapdoor to determine the preimages $(x_1,x_2)$ that hash onto $y$, and verifies that
  $$d\cdot(x_1\oplus x_2)=0.$$
- This string $d$ is orthogonal to both preimages and it is likely very difficult to consistently obtain the pair $(d,y)$ absent a quantum computer (or knowledge of the factors of $N$).

Does this potentially suggest a simpler algorithm to *factor* a number $N$ that is promised to be the product of two large primes?

For example, if I wish to factor a test integer $N$ that is known to be the product of two primes, and I have access to a NISQ-era quantum computer of large enough size, could I:

1. Prepare $\sum|x\rangle|x^2\bmod N\rangle$;
2. Measure the first and second registers in the Hadamard and computational basis, respectively, to generate pairs $(d_i,y_i)$;
3. Repeat the above a polynomial number of times (say, a million or so times);
4. And feed these pairs $(d_i,y_i)$ into a supercomputer, to somehow simplify a search for the factors of $N$?

Are many pairs $(d,y)$ with $d\cdot(x_1\oplus x_2)=0$ and $x_1^2\bmod N=x_2^2\bmod N=y$ in any way useful to factor $N$?

I suspect the answer is no, as each $y$ will be uniformly distributed over all outputs and only knowing one bit of information about the preimages that map onto $y$ is not so useful to factor $N$, but I'm not sure.

<sup>I recently asked this on [Quantum-Computing Stack Exchange](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/), but perhaps this is a better forum, and I deleted my post there.</sup>